# Align points summarized by a variable with points dodged by the same variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data from two different data sets. The first, `dat1` contains multiple points. The 2nd `dat2` contains only the max values for each Season-Species group in `dat1`. I am trying to plot `dat1` and then want to plot larger shapes that highlight the max values for each Season-Species group, that is, `dat2`.

Data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat1 <- structure(list(Season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor"), 
        Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("BHS", "MTG"), class = "factor"), 
        CovGrain = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("CanCov_30", "CanCov_500", "CanCov_1000", 
        "NDVI_30", "NDVI_500", "NDVI_1000", "Slope_30", "Slope_500", 
        "Slope_1000", "SlopeVar_30", "SlopeVar_500", "SlopeVar_1000"
        ), class = "factor"), Count = c(4L, 19L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 14L, 
        14L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 9L)), .Names = c("Season", "Species", 
    "CovGrain", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 45L, 46L, 47L))

dat2 <- dat1 %>% group_by(Season, Species) %>% 
  filter(Count == max(Count)) %>% as.data.frame()


ggplot(dat1, aes(x = CovGrain, y = Count)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species, color = Species),
             alpha = 0.5, stroke = 3, size = 3, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~Season, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = CovGrain, y = Count), shape = 23, 
             stroke = 2, size = 6, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

In the plot below I want the black triangles to be correctly dodged so that they outline the largest point of each group.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean variable in the original data which indicates if 'Count' is at maximum, grouped by 'Season' and 'Species'. Use `scale_alpha_manual` to set `alpha` to `0` for `FALSE` (i.e. "Count" not at `max`). Dodge by "Species" using `group = Species`.

```
dat1 <- dat1 %>% group_by(Season, Species) %>%
  mutate(max_count = Count == max(Count))

pos <- position_dodge(0.5)

ggplot(dat1, aes(x = CovGrain, y = Count)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), position = pos) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = max_count, group = Species), shape = 23, size = 6, position = pos) +
  facet_wrap(~ Season) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0, 1), guide = "none") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Slick! very simple and transferable to the larger data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit hacky, and there is probably a better solution, but one way is to create a new x variable with your own randomness. The hacky part comes from first doing `geom_point(size = -1)` to get it to maintain the x-axis. So, not elegant, by any means, but gets you what you want, I think.

```
dat1$id <- 1:nrow(dat1)

dat2 <- dat1 %>% 
    group_by(Season, Species, Cov) %>% 
    filter(Count == max(Count)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

randomness <- rnorm(nrow(dat1), 0, 0.5)
dat1$new_x <- as.integer(dat1$CovGrain) + randomness
dat2$new_x <- as.integer(dat2$CovGrain) + randomness[dat2$id]

ggplot(dat1, aes(x = CovGrain, y = Count)) +
  geom_point(size = -1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = new_x, fill = Species, color = Species),
             alpha = 0.5, stroke = 3, size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~Season, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = new_x, y = Count), shape = 23, 
             stroke = 2, size = 6) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]